# Transfer function DC motor

Tags: motor, dc, pid-controller, matlab

I'm trying modeling a PID controller for a motor. This PID will limit the motor's inrush current. However, I don't know how to model my DC motor.

For me, the equation of the system is: K/((Js+b)(Ls+R)+K²)

With: k corresponds to the torque constant of the motor and is equal to the electromotive force constant when the motor is at no load (Nm/A or N/rad/s).

J is the moment of inertia of the rotor (Kg/m²).

b is the viscous friction constant of the motor (I can't find its value).

R is the electrical resistance.

L is the electrical inductance.

The motor's datasheet (I use the ref 82 830 502): https://docs.rs-online.com/d273/0900766b8009b146.pdf

If someone can help me to find the transfer function it will be a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Laplace schematic equivalent ...
Note that you need probably the current variable Ia.
Here, the only input variable is U.

See also [this](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip), a DC motor is also designed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is the transfer function of the motor, where the input is applied voltage and the output is angular velocity of the motor shaft. So, multiply this TF by the PID TF to give the system's OLTF, then close the loop around the OLTF to give the system's CLTF.

This will produce a closed loop velocity control system. If you want position control you need to include an integrator in the OLTF (i.e., integral of angular velocity is angular displacement).

Answer (score 0):

In my lessons on control theory I have used with success the following transfer function for a DC controlled motor **(output: Rotation speed n in rad/s)**

**H1(s)=N(s)/Vin(s)=Forward path/(1+Loop Gain)=Hf(s)/(1+km*Hf)** with

**(1)** Forward Hf(S)=ka/[(Ra+sLa)(kr+s*MI)]

**(2)** Feedback function F(s)=km

**Explanation:**

Torque factor ka=Torque/anchor current

Electrical anchor parameter: Ra, La

Friction factor kr

Factor for induced back voltage (Vi):  km=Vi/w

MI: Moment of intertia

From this, it is possible to rewrite the function H(s):

**H1(s)=kdc/(1+sT1)(1+sT2)]**

**Comment**: This simple P-T2 behaviour (proportional with two time constants) can easily be verified using the step response of the DC motor.

Because of w=d(phi)/dt we can find **another function** with angle **PHI(s) as output** variable:

**H2(s)=PHI(s)/Vin(s)=(1/s) * H1(s)**